# MLflow: INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE: Unsupported URI './mlruns' for model registry store

Tags: python, mlflow

I got this error when I was trying to have a model registered in the model registry. Could someone help me?

```
RestException: INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE: Unsupported URI './mlruns' for model registry store. 
Supported schemes are: ['postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite', 'mssql']. 
See https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#storage for how to setup a compatible server.
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Mlflow required DB as datastore for Model Registry
So you have to run tracking server with DB as backend-store and log model to this tracking server.
The easiest way to use DB is to use SQLite.

```
mlflow server \
    --backend-store-uri sqlite:///mlflow.db \
    --default-artifact-root ./artifacts \
    --host 0.0.0.0
```

And set MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI environment variable to *http://localhost:5000* or

```
mlflow.set_tracking_uri("http://localhost:5000")
```

After got to http://localhost:5000 and you can register a logged model from UI or from the code.

Comment: My experiments disappeared after adding a backend-store-uri. Is there a way to keep them?

Comment: ```mlflow server \
    --backend-store-uri sqlite:///mlflow.db \
    --default-artifact-root ./mlruns \
    --host 0.0.0.0
```
Use this command. Since default artifact location for mlflow is ./mlruns. @FernandoWittmann

Comment: @Parthchokhra right. Now you are using another mlflow backend not your default

Comment: @Parthchokhra thanks! but unfortunately, that doesn't work when using an S3 path as artifact-root. Posted more details in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72150148/experiments-disappear-when-adding-backend-store-uri).

Comment: @Parthchokhra it is working. Check out this [link](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#scenario-4-mlflow-with-remote-tracking-server-backend-and-artifact-stores)