# UI does display data in MLflow

Tags: databricks, mlflow

This is in reference to rather comment (not answer), I added here: [MLflow: INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE: Unsupported URI './mlruns' for model registry store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63255631/mlflow-invalid-parameter-value-unsupported-uri-mlruns-for-model-registry-s/66371465#66371465)

I extracted files from [here](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/tree/master/examples/sklearn_elasticnet_wine)

```
train.py     MLproject     wine-quality.csv
```

These are in directory:`feb24MLFLOW`

I am in directory `feb24MLFLOW` with following contents

```
:memory          mlruns           train.py         wine-quality.csv
```

When I run following command

```
mlflow server --backend-store-uri sqlite:///:memory --default-artifact-root ./mlruns
```

**The UI loads but does not show any data in it neigther does database as below. see screenshot.**
[image]
I am using `--default-artifact-root ./mlruns` flag because, when I print  print(mlflow.get_tracking_uri()), I get the current directory

```
file:///<mydirectorylocations>/feb24MLFLOW/mlruns
```

For some reason I see my database is not updating (or inserting). I checked that with in terminal.

```
$  sqlite3
sqlite> .open :memory 
sqlite> .tables
alembic_version        metrics                registered_model_tags
experiment_tags        model_version_tags     registered_models    
experiments            model_versions         runs                 
latest_metrics         params                 tags                 
sqlite> select * from runs;
sqlite>
```

As you can see there is no data after running `select * from runs` above.

Please note that I have following contents in

```
./mlruns

d6db5cf1443d49c19971a1b8b606d692 meta.yaml

Can somebody suggest I show results in the UI? or insert in databse? or what am I doing wrong?
```

Please note that when I run `mlflow ui`, I see data in the UI but I get:

```
error_code: "INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE"
message: " Model registry functionality is unavailable; got unsupported URI './mlruns' for model registry data storage. Supported URI schemes are: ['postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite', 'mssql']. See https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#storage for how to run an MLflow server against one of the supported backend storage locations."
```

Comment: I think, when specify a db in memory like `sqlite:///:memory`, it's empty every time you launch airflow server. The solution is not to use :memory? as it's not persistent

Comment: Right, I tried with sqlite://mydb.db. Still dont see results.

Comment: In that case if this server is live and now I execute eg python train.py, should not that update the databse? (It does not, it throws, No ID error)

Comment: remember to run server from the same directory your run projects? so that they both see ./mlruns in the same place/

Comment: Of coursre, as outlined above, I am in the folder where mlruns is located. And from there when I rul mlflow ui, project runs fine. but I cannot serve it. I think I am missing some environment config. I am not sure I am I missing. But if I am missing env why does it run with mlflow ui.