# Experiments disappear when adding --backend-store-uri

Tags: mlflow

I have an EC2 instance running a mlflow server using the following command:

```
mlflow server -h 0.0.0.0 --default-artifact-root s3://xxxx
```

After running multiple experiments, I was trying to register the best one. However, when trying to register or accessing the tab "Models", I get the following error:

> INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE: Model registry functionality is unavailable; got unsupported URI './mlruns' for model registry data storage. Supported URI schemes are: ['postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite', 'mssql']. See https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#storage for how to run an MLflow server against one of the supported backend storage locations.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63255631/mlflow-invalid-parameter-value-unsupported-uri-mlruns-for-model-registry-s) suggested adding a `backend-store-uri`:

```
mlflow server -h 0.0.0.0 --default-artifact-root --backend-store-uri sqlite:///mlflow.db
```

That solved the above issue, however, now all experiments are gone. The Experiments tab is blank. Is there a way to add a `backend-store-uri` after running multiple experiments while keeping all of them?

Answer (score 0):

By default MLFlow uses the local file system to store your experiment, if you switch later on to a DB-based solution like you did, the database will be empty, as a result you won't see your past experiments (from the [documentation](https://mlflow.org/docs/2.3.0/cli.html#cmdoption-mlflow-server-backend-store-uri)):

> --backend-store-uri 
> URI to which to persist experiment and run data. Acceptable URIs are
> SQLAlchemy-compatible database connection strings (e.g.
> ‘sqlite:///path/to/file.db’) or local filesystem URIs (e.g.
> ‘file:///absolute/path/to/directory’). By default, data will be logged
> to the ./mlruns directory.

I can't seem to find a reference right now, but I have read that data won't be migrated upon switching `--backend-store-uri`, so what you are seeing it expected unfortunately, I am not aware of any easy way to export and re-import data.